# How to resolve unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1 in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I am using chrome driver 2.35(tried till v 2.9) and chrome browser v 65.

gems used:
watir 6.10.3
selenium-webdriver 3.11.0

error message:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:142:in `connect_until_stable'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:72:in `block in start'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:39:in `locked'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:69:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/driver.rb:42:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:44:in `for'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.11.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:85:in `for'
    from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/watir-6.10.3/lib/watir/browser.rb:48:in `initialize'
```

Comment: try upgrading chrome driver to `ChromeDriver 2.37`. this version supports `Chrome 64-66`

Comment: still I am getting the same error.

Comment: when I use chromedriver v 2.7 the browser is getting launched but it throws below error `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'`

Comment: this is a known issue in Chrome 65 with Chrome Driver <2.35 versions. It is not appearing in 2.36. It could have resurfaced in 2.37 again. Try with `2.36` version

Comment: No luck again the same error.I wonder how the browser is getting launched when I use chromedriver v 2.7 but which throws the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded the chrome version to 62 and disabled auto update to resolve this issue.
Older version available [here](https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php)
Before installing the older version some steps needs to be followed.

1. Uninstall current version of chrome
2. Navigate to C:\Users\\AppData\Local and delete google
   directory
3. Navigate to C:\Program Files (x86) and delete google directory
4. Install the intended older version
5. Don't open the chrome browser,chrome gets updated automatically.
6. Type 'msconfig' in run command  and ensure google update services are in 'stopped' status
7. Navigate to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google' and rename 'update'
   directory to some other name.If renaming is denied ensure that all
   chrome related tasks are closed in task manager and then try
   renaming.
8. Now open chrome and navigate to Help->About Google Chrome.If you get
   a error message for update then chrome won't get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, unable to connect chromedriver. So instead of using different chrome driver versions, I have just added gem called **chromedriver-helper** to my gem list, now works fine.

Comment: I am getting the same error.I have added the chromedriver-helper to gem list.